# Create a server based digital signature services on Windows

Tags: digital-signature

I want to develop a system for digital signature services. here is the summary of my system scenario:

1. Private keys are stored on HSM(e.g. nShield Connect) rather than smart card
2. HSM is connected with a central application server where Cryptographic operation or digital signing process is performed
3. Users upload documents and send signing request to application server through third party applications (e.g. internet explorer)
4. Application server extract private keys from HSM
5. Then server sign the document and return it to the user.

   How I can create a virtual server in Windows platform? Or from where I will start?

Note:

Biometric authentication may be applied to access private key in future

Comment: Generally you don't want to or can't `extract private keys from HSM`. Do you mean the app server has the HSM sign?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really an infosec question. Perhaps serverfault?

Comment: Your stated question is "How I can create a virtual server in Windows platform?", which is a Windows question, not a security question.